# How to preserve Git commit history when refactoring an existing project to a fresh vue-cli created one?

Tags: javascript, git, typescript, vue.js

So, I have this project of mine created with **Vue** and **vue-cli** that I want to refactor. I want to implement **Typescript** in it, and was recommended to start a fresh project with [Vue CLI 3](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create).

Here is the repo of my project, if curious: https://github.com/kamatheuska/portafolio-client

My issue is that I will lose track of my project's commit history if I start a new one. I want to preserve my git commit history and metadata as much as posible.

First thing I would do is:

```
vue create refactored-project
```

and then set it to build with **Typescript**. Now how can I move the **Git commit history** or similar from the old project to this one, I have no idea. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's wrong with removing all files, commiting that, then doing `vue create refactored-project`? I don't see why you can't do that, and that preserves the Git history.

Comment: @nbokmans do you mean erase everything except `.git`?

Comment: Create a new branch, delete every file, commit that, and start again?

Comment: If you're starting over, why not *start over*? Create a new git repo and "archive" the old one. Your history won't be lost, but there's no value in including that history in your new project that doesn't actually share any history.

Comment: @meagar I am not starting over, I have a working project which I want to refactor to include `Typescript` and **typechecking**, which doesn't require extreme changing, but some transition to **typechecking**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to rewrite everything from scratch there is nothing wrong with making a clean break and archiving the old repo.

However I'm guessing you will want to keep much of the business logic and move/copy files to new places in the structure and want to keep the history to aid in figuring out why something was done in a particular way.

The easiest solution is to move *all* current files to a single folder "old" and start the new project in the same repo. As you implement new functionality delete the refactored old files, don't try to keep both projects active at the same time, that is what branches and old commits are for. If you are meticulous about it you will get a "progress bar" of how close you are to completing the refactor: when the "old"-folder is empty everything has been implemented in the new structure.

When you copy large parts of files git will do a reasonable job of detecting that and providing a coherent code history.

---

There is a more complicated solution: git allows you to have multiple source roots. That is mostly for merging two existing projects though, not really applicable here.

Comment: Well, that is my case. I am not starting a new, just have to refactor my code to work with `typescript`, so it isn't a big transformation on my `src`, but more on the `vue-cli` and building side of things.

Comment: thanks for the answer, now I know what I have to do.