# How to rename a method in Visual Studio and keep history?

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, refactoring, visual-studio-2019

We use Git in combination with Visual Studio 2019 to track our files.

VisualStudio shows a little info text.
(e. g. `4 references | username, 19 minutes ago | 2 authors, 4 changes`).

How to preserver this "history" on rename refactor of the method (the build-in method-rename refactor doesn't keep it)? Git shows it in the log correctly but VisualStudio shows "4 references | 0 changes | 0 authors, 0 changes"
Same question for moving the method to another file or class.

To clearify this is not a git specific question. The normal git history is fine. I'd like to keep the presentation in VisualStudio correct.

Comment: I understand this was a Visual Studio question first, but as far as I know, the integration of `git log --follow` is not well supported by such an IDE. Hence my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in "[How do I refactor my code to a new file and preserve git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40466759/6309)", Git itself can be able to patch the history with [`git log --follow`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---follow), or [`git diff -C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt--Cltngt)

However, those options are not well integrated in Visual Studio 2019.

So at the very least, set a tag (or a [copy as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54147371/6309)) in order to be able to go back to a state where your old files have their history.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't solve my problem. The git history is fine and the movement is correctly trackt. I concrete want visual VisualStudio to keep the history of the method in the litle hinttext above each method. I only rename the method but the tooltip set the modification count to 0

Comment: @finder2 I understand it does not solve the problem: I try to convey this does not seem supported by Visual Studio 2019.